# JavaScript curry / schönfinkeln

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have the following functions declared

```
function curry(fn) {
    var args = [];
    // push everything but function itself into args
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return function() {
        var args2 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args2.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        var argstotal = args.concat(args2);
        return fn.apply(argstotal);
    };
}

function add(a,b){return a + b};
```

What im trying to do is obvious, I want to curry the add function which works great itself

```
var addCurry = curry(add);
addCurry(10, 20, 12314) // should deliver 30, gives NaN
```

Somehow it returns NaN and I dont know what Im doing wrong... Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error here: `return fn.apply(argstotal)`

The first argument to [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is a scope, the value of `this` within the invocation, *not* the first argument. If you were to print out the `arguments` from within your curried function, you would see:

```js
function curry(fn) {
  var args = [];
  // push everything but function itself into args
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  return function() {
    var args2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      args2.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    var argstotal = args.concat(args2);
    return fn.apply(argstotal);
  };
}

function add(a, b) {
  console.log('debug', this, arguments);
  return a + b;
}

var cadd = curry(add, 1);
cadd(2);
```

You can very easily fix this in two ways:

1. Pass `this` through to the curried function
2. Ignore `this` and do not set it for curried functions

The first option is probably better, as it will surprise developers less. You can implement that using:

```js
function curry(fn) {
  var args = [];
  // push everything but function itself into args
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  return function() {
    var args2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      args2.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    var argstotal = args.concat(args2);
    return fn.apply(this, argstotal); // <-- only change
  };
}

function add(a, b) {
  console.log('debug', /* this, */ arguments);
  return a + b;
}

var cadd = curry(add, 1);
cadd(2);
```

The second option can be implemented with `fn.apply(null, argstotal)`.